# ios build failed clang: error : linker command failed with exit code

Tags: ios, react-native, build

I have build failed problem.

My coworker had build intel cpu but I have M1 chip.

If i have build ios application i used arch "-x86_64 react-native run-ios" this command

I want to use "react-native run-ios" this command

thank you.

Here is my react-native info

> System:
> OS: macOS 12.2.1
> CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
> Memory: 607.44 MB / 16.00 GB
> Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh   Binaries:
> Node: 16.6.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/node
> Yarn: 1.22.17 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
> npm: 8.1.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/npm
> Watchman: 2022.01.31.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman   Managers:
> CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod   SDKs:
> iOS SDK:
> Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
> Android SDK:
> API Levels: 23, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
> Build Tools: 23.0.1, 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 31.0.0
> System Images: android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
> Android NDK: Not Found   IDEs:
> Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292
> Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild   Languages:
> Java: 1.8.0_312 - /usr/bin/javac   npmPackages:
> @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
> react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
> react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2
> react-native-macos: Not Found   npmGlobalPackages:
> *react-native*: Not Found

here is build failed log

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> The following build commands failed:
> Ld /Users/[myuserName]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[projectName]-btfwqkajsbjqdeemhrjkhjomolws/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/[projectName].app/[projectName] normal (in target '[projectName]' from project '[projectName]')
> (1 failure)

Comment: Seems you need to check reacnative installation on your Mac

Comment: @PtitXav can you tell me more specifications please